# Delete lambda function in gulp script

Tags: javascript, lambda, gulp, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

[image]   I wrote a gulp script for automating the deletion of Lambda in gulp script.

```
    Code :
   **gulp.task('DeleteLambda', function () {
        loggingManager.deleteLambda("TestRawat", function () {
            console.log("------------------lambda Deleted.");
        });**

        Error : requestId: undefined,

> Blockquote

      retryable: true } 'UnknownError: Service Unavailable at Object.extractError
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I am gettin error 'UnknownError: Service Unavailable at Object.extractError @D.Simon

Comment: @D.Simon for more details I added the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure the region or region code in your code .

```
 AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
cloudformation = new AWS.CloudFormation({ region: "us-west-2" });
```